# Api to lock the device blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

Im trying to develop a blackberry native app, whose function is to lock the device. Is it possible to set the device lock state? should i use any third party api?

I found this java code..

ApplicationManager appman =  ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
appman.lockSystem(true);

Anything similar in c++?

Answer (score 0):

No. Is not possible with the current API.
You should use some trick such as show a dialog window or other.

You can do is understand the state of the device using the code below.

```
if (myHomeScreen.lockState == DeviceLockState.Unknown) {
    console.log("No idea");
} else if (myHomeScreen.lockState == DeviceLockState.Unlocked) {
           console.log("Unlocked");
} else if (myHomeScreen.lockState == DeviceLockState.ScreenLocked) {
    console.log("Screen locked");
} else if (myHomeScreen.lockState == DeviceLockState.PasswordLocked) {
    console.log("Password locked");
} else if (myHomeScreen.lockState == DeviceLockState.PinBlocked) {
       console.log("PIN blocked");
}
```

This is an extract of this [documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__platform__homescreen.html).

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps, we can lower the screen timeout seconds. Is that possible?

Comment: I think is not possible via thirds's app. (however the less timeout is 1 minute) There is an app that prevents from unwanted unlock of the smartphone and it works showing a custom popup or using others similar trick.

Comment: Oh..okay. Thanks for your help